# JwtBearerAuthentication does not set the HttpContext User

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, bearer-token, jwt

I am having enormous difficulty finding relevant information on this topic: JwtBearerAuthentication in .NetCore Web API.  The token is an OIDC id token issued by IdentityServer and sent via the front-end client application.  The token is received and validated correctly, resulting in an authenticated ClaimsPrincipal with 15 claims, but that principal is not present in the HttpContext when the request reaches the application.  There is an anonymous unauthenticated user, not the one present when the token is validated.

This api was conceived by its authors (not me) to use OIDC cookie authentication, but I am trying to convert it to use JWT bearer authentication.

As far as I can tell, I am doing everything correctly according to all the examples I can find and I am out of ideas.  Any help is appreciated.

I have posted the entire Startup.cs file below, sorry for all the code but you should be able to see all the relevant stuff...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autofac;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Autofac.Configuration;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using CAS.Authorization.Api.Configuration;
using CAS.Authorization.Api.Defaults.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;

namespace CAS.Authorization.Api
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    //options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                   // options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                //.AddCookie()
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:40800";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:40800",
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidAudience = "http://localhost:22426"
                    };
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                    {
                        OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                        {
                            //This does not work, however the context.Principal IS authenticated
                            //and DOES have claims (15 of them).
                            context.HttpContext.User = context.Principal;
                        }
                    };
                });
            //.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            //{
            //    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            //    options.Authority = "http://localhost:40800";
            //    options.ClientId = "defaultClientId";
            //    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            //    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            //    options.ResponseType = "code";
            //    options.Scope.Add("profile");
            //    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            //    options.SaveTokens = true;
            //    options.ClaimActions.MapAllExcept("iss", "nbf", "exp", "aud", "nonce", "iat", "c_hash");
            //});

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddAuthorization(PolicyConfiguration.SetupPolicies);

            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AccessPolicyHandler>();
            services.AddTransient<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();

            //Api Versioning
            //services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
            //{
            //    o.ReportApiVersions = true;
            //    o.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
            //});

            services.Configure<BusSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("BusSettings"));

            //Swagger
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "CAS Authorization API", Version = "v1" });
                
                //Locate the XML file being generated by ASP.NET...
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.XML";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);

                //... and tell Swagger to use those XML comments.
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });

            // Add Autofac
            // ConfigurationModule accepts JSON configuration for other modules/components to register,
            // instead of having references here to those modules, directly.
            // If we ever want to remove those direct references, this should still work.
            // config.AddJsonFile comes from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            config.AddJsonFile("modules.json");

            // Register the ConfigurationModule with Autofac.
            var module = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyModules();
            builder.RegisterModule(module);
            builder.Populate(services);

            var container = builder.Build();
            return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
                
            }

            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();

            //Swagger UI
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CAS Authorization API - v1");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Edited to add example of attempt to access the the user, in method GetClaimsByOrganization below:

```
    public class UserIdentityService : IUserIdentityService
    {
        private HttpContext _context;

        public UserIdentityService(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            _context = contextAccessor?.HttpContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        public string UserName => _context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

        public Guid Sub => Guid.Parse(_context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);

        public Claim[] GetPermissionClaims(string permissionName, string resourceName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(permissionName)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid permission name");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceName)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid resource name");

            return _context.User?.Claims?.Where(c => c.Type.Contains("ORG:") && c.Value == resourceName.ToUpper() + permissionName.ToUpper()).ToArray();
        }

        public Claim[] GetClaimsByOrganization(string orgName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orgName)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid organization name");

            return _context.User?.Claims?.Where(c => c.Type == "ORG:" + orgName.ToUpper()).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: would please show where you are trying to access the user object

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post to add an example of attempt to access the User.

Comment: check this two links [startup.cs](https://github.com/ogomaemmanuel/VueChatApp/blob/master/Startup.cs) and [controller with authorize attribute](https://github.com/ogomaemmanuel/VueChatApp/blob/master/Features/Chat/Controllers/ChatsController.cs) , I do not think you have to set User in the Startup class, .Net core should do that, but your UserIdentityService must be called from a controller with Authorize attribute, this may help

Comment: Thanks for looking at this and sharing those examples. I understand that it should not be necessary to set the User in Startup, but doing that does permit me to break on that and see that the context.Principal does have the correct value. That shows that the token is received and validated and all the expected claims are present. But that principal is not the one in HttpContext when accessed later. The Authorize attribute is on the controller involved and that makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved. This was a proof of concept with Identity Server, client application, and API all running in Visual Studio Debug with as many default settings as possible.  I was hitting the API with http.  When I hit it on its https port, it worked.  Evidently the authentication middleware only sets the user when the request uses https.